# How to Build NetBeans Project into split JARs? (one with the mainclass, others as libraries)

Tags: netbeans, ant, jar

I have a project which builds into a single JAR in Netbeans.

However, to implement a basic auto update feature, I would like to move at least one of the packages (the HTTPClient package) to a separate JAR, as well as build a new JAR with a second Main Class in a different package.

That way both the current Mainclass and the Updater Mainclass can use the same HTTPClient package.

But... HOW?

Something to do with the build-impl.xml file. But where? What to change?

Comment: 1 project == 1 jar was a pretty fundamental assumption when the NB project system was designed.  It may have changed but I am not familiar with that change.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate project for your HTTPClient package which creates a single jar file.

Your main project then uses this project (and the created jar). You can use "Add project..." at the libraries of your main project and select the HTTPClient project.